# C# linq Create a new item related to a function against previous data

Tags: c#, linq

```
List<History> data = new List<History>(){   
 new History() {Symbol="a", Close = 1.0m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 1) },
 new History() {Symbol="a", Close = 1.2m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 2) },
 new History() {Symbol="a", Close = 1.3m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 3) },
 new History() {Symbol="b", Close = 1.2m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 1) },
 new History() {Symbol="b", Close = 1.2m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 2) },
 new History() {Symbol="b", Close = 1.3m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 3) },
};

var StockGroupList = data
 .GroupBy(o => o.Symbol)
 .OrderBy(o => o.Key)
 .ToList();
```

I want create a new List like

```
select new { Symbol, Close, Date, Vol};
```

Here `Vol` is the two day standard deviation e.g `Vol` of `Symbol="a"` at `2016, 2, 3` is  function of `close` for `2016, 2, 3` and `2016, 2, 2`. Moreover, The `Vol` of first day (e.g `2016, 2, 1`) is default as `Vol = 0`.

Expected output:

```
List<dynamic> NewData = new List<dynamic>
{ 
 new { Symbol = "a", Close = 1.0m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 1), Vol = 0 },
 new { Symbol = "a", Close = 1.0m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 2), Vol = SD(Close of 2016, 2, 1, Close of 2016, 2, 2) },
 new { Symbol = "a", Close = 1.0m, Date = new DateTime(2016, 2, 3), Vol = SD(Close of 2016, 2, 2, Close of 2016, 2, 3) },
                                            ......
};
```

You can regard `SD(x,y)` as a given function, saying `SD(x,y) = x+y` simply.
Furthermore, if the parameter of `SD` is a `List` say `List[Close of 2016, 2, 2, Close of 2016, 2, 3)]`, then how could I do?

And if `SD` is following form

```
decimal OneStdDev = (decimal)(new DescriptiveStatistics(data.Select(o => (double)o.Close)).StandardDeviation);
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you need grouping in this case, if I understand your problem you want to calculate `SD` between current and previous history records.

You could do this using `Linq` extension methods.

```
var results = data          
                .Take(1)
                .Select(x=>new {x.Symbol, x.Close, x.Date, Vol = 0.0m})
                .Concat(data.Zip(data.Skip(1), (first,second) => 
                                 new 
                                 {
                                     second.Symbol, 
                                     second.Close, 
                                     second.Date, 
                                     Vol = first.Close + second.Close  // Use whatever logic you want.
                                 }
                        ));
```

**Output:**

```
Symbol =a, Close=1.0, Date=2/1/2016 12:00:00 AM, Vol = 0.0
Symbol =a, Close=1.2, Date=2/2/2016 12:00:00 AM, Vol = 2.2
Symbol =a, Close=1.3, Date=2/3/2016 12:00:00 AM, Vol = 2.5
Symbol =b, Close=1.2, Date=2/1/2016 12:00:00 AM, Vol = 2.5
Symbol =b, Close=1.2, Date=2/2/2016 12:00:00 AM, Vol = 2.4
Symbol =b, Close=1.3, Date=2/3/2016 12:00:00 AM, Vol = 2.5
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HolhGf)

Comment: How to write when number is very large, say the parameters of `SD` are 10 days `close` before, and the first 10 day `close` is default as 0. Thanks

Comment: That's followup question, I would suggest post new question. It might confuse people reaching with similar problem if we include more than what is asked in the question.